# Room Database: how to get data one time?

Tags: android, android-room

this my Database

```
@Database(entities = [UserModel::class], version = 1,exportSchema = false)
abstract class UserRoomDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getUserDao() : UserDAO

    companion object{
        @Volatile
        private var instance : UserRoomDatabase?= null
        fun getInstance(context : Context): UserRoomDatabase{
            if(instance==null)
                instance = Room
                    .databaseBuilder(context,UserRoomDatabase::class.java,"UserRoomDatabase")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            return instance!!
        }
    }
}
```

DAO interface

```
@Dao
interface UserDAO {
    @Query("select * from user_table where _id =:id")
    fun readUserByIdSyncDAO(id : String) : UserModel
}
```

Repository

```
class UserRepository(context : Context) {
    private val userDAO : UserDAO
    init {
        val userDatabase: UserRoomDatabase = UserRoomDatabase.getInstance(context)
        userDAO = userDatabase.getUserDao()
    }
fun readUserByIdSyncDAO(id : String) : UserModel = userDAO.readUserByIdSyncDAO(id)
}
```

ViewModel

```
class UserViewModel(private val userRepository: UserRepository) : ViewModel() {
       fun readUserByIdSyncDAO(id : String) : UserModel = userRepository.readUserByIdSyncDAO(id)
}
```

and this is the way i use

```
 val userModel = viewModel.readUserByIdSyncDAO(userId)
        Log.e(TAG,userModel.toString())
```

but i got the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList com.animals.snowy.models.UserModel.getFriends()' on a null object reference
```

why this error appear and how can i fix it?

and i wonder if i use allowMainThreadQueries() in Database, is it better or worse for app?

Comment: `is it better or worse for app?` definitely not better

Comment: Avoid using `allowMainThreadQueries()` in production

Comment: so do you other way to solve my problem?